# When I pass MapView to child of Touchable element then press events works not properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

platform: ios 10.3
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.48.3",
"react-native-maps": "^0.16.4",

The reason why I should track double press event is that when I press on map then header in my app is toggling, when I make double press it toggling 2 times, I need on double press don't toggle header, the toggling similar to google map app.

And when I make quick double tap, second tap is not processed they all must be processed. What can it be? Seems like double press zoom doesn't let for my second tap events process.
If instead MapView I put View, handlers works correctly

my code:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPressIn={() => {console.log('onPress');}}
    onPressOut={() => {console.log('onPressOut');}}
>
    <MapView
        region={region}
        ref={ref => { this.mapView = ref }}
        style={s.mapView}
        onLayout={() => this.onLayout(coordinates)}
        onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
        showsUserLocation
    >
    </MapView>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

you can look video https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RZJBs8J7gz3lRBOZ5DUTYIcCF48tib5P